What is the DGLA controlling deformations of a group representation?
Fix a (discrete) group $G$, characteristic zero field $k$ and representation $\rho_0: G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$. I want to consider the formal deformations of $\rho_0$.
My understanding is there is a dgla (differential graded Lie algebra) that controls these deformations, in the sense that I can recover my deformation problem by taking solutions to the Maurer-Cartan equation with coefficients in this dgla (e.g. citation: Thm. 5.3 in Lurie's ICM address).
Q1: What is (a model of) this dgla?
I presume if I wanted a dga instead, a natural choice would be the bar construction in group cohomology. My ideal hope is that the dgla is in some way related to the dga:
Q2: Is there some way of getting such a dgla from this dga?
(My motivation is I am trying to understand some general things in deformation theory. The most natural (to me as a number theorist) examples I care about are group representations. But to connect this to the modern literature on deformation theory I seem to want my deformation problem to be controlled by a dgla.
I also apologize if this question is basic, I am having some difficulty navigating the relevant literature).

This dgla is just the Lie algebra of vector fields on the formal neighborhood of your representation in the representation variety. In general (when the point is not smooth) it is Koszul dual (not precisely, pronilpotent Lie algebra, which is dual vector space of Koszul dual Lie coalgebra) of de Rham complex of that formal nbhd.

Any dga has an underlying dgla given by commutator brackets. Based on the tangent spaces to representation varieties and example 5.10 of Lurie, I expect this to be the right dgla here.

I'll look into these suggestions, thank you.
@PhilTosteson I'm not sure about this as I don't think it gives me the right Maurer-Cartan solutions.

@affy I see, just to be clear, I mean the underlying dgla of the Bar construction that computes $Ext_G^*(\rho,\rho)$. (I haven't done any computations, so of course this may be completely wrong).

@PhilTosteson Yes, I think we're on the same page (though if we're not the mistake is certainly mine):
$Ext^_G(\rho, \rho) \cong H^(G, \mathrm{End}(\rho)$, and the Bar construction of this is my dga.
There is a MC equation in dgas: ${ \xi \in C^1 \otimes_k \mathfrak{m}_A | d\xi + \xi \cdot \xi = 0}$,
and the Bar construction is such that one can check by hand that solutions to the MC equation for the Bar construction correspond to extensions.
But I think this pretty much rules out that the same is true if one takes the MC equation with the obvious induced dgla structure instead.

@affy Does it help that this is a graded lie algebra, so that in degree 1 the commutators are actually anti-commutators?

@PhilTosteson Oh I think you're totally right, I missed that. Thank you so much!
